# Explode array values using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark and I need to explode my array of values in such a way that each value gets assigned to a new column. I tried using explode but I couldn't get the desired output.Below is my output

```
+---------------+----------+------------------+----------+---------+------------+--------------------+
|account_balance|account_id|credit_Card_Number|first_name|last_name|phone_number|        transactions|
+---------------+----------+------------------+----------+---------+------------+--------------------+
|         100000|     12345|             12345|       abc|      xyz|  1234567890|[1000, 01/06/2020...|
|         100000|     12345|             12345|       abc|      xyz|  1234567890|[1100, 02/06/2020...|
|         100000|     12345|             12345|       abc|      xyz|  1234567890|[6146, 02/06/2020...|
|         100000|     12345|             12345|       abc|      xyz|  1234567890|[253, 03/06/2020,...|
|         100000|     12345|             12345|       abc|      xyz|  1234567890|[4521, 04/06/2020...|
|         100000|     12345|             12345|       abc|      xyz|  1234567890|[955, 05/06/2020,...|
+---------------+----------+------------------+----------+---------+------------+--------------------+
```

Below is the schema of the program

```
root
 |-- account_balance: long (nullable = true)
 |-- account_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- credit_Card_Number: long (nullable = true)
 |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- phone_number: long (nullable = true)
 |-- transactions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- amount: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- shop: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- transaction_code: string (nullable = true)
```

I want an output in which I have additional columns of amount,date,shop,transaction_code with their respective values

```
amount date        shop     transaction_code
1000   01/06/2020  amazon      buy
1100   02/06/2020  amazon      sell
6146   02/06/2020  ebay        buy
253    03/06/2020  ebay        buy 
4521   04/06/2020  amazon      buy
955    05/06/2020  amazon      buy
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use **`explode`** and then split the **`struct`** fileds, finally drop the newly exploded and transactions array columns.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

#got only some columns from json
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- account_balance: long (nullable = true)
# |-- transactions: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |-- amount: long (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
df.selectExpr("*","explode(transactions)").select("*","col.*").drop(*['col','transactions']).show()
#+---------------+------+--------+
#|account_balance|amount|    date|
#+---------------+------+--------+
#|             10|  1000|20200202|
#+---------------+------+--------+
```

Comment: Great solution ! Thank you so much !