# How to extract selected elements from array using "explode" in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Spark dataframe `spdf` with data that looks as follows:

```
player_name    team_history

John           [{Rangers, Center, Active}, {Blackhawks, Center, Former}, {Kings, Center, Former}],
Bob            [{Devils, Defense, Active}, {Maple Leafs, Defense, Former}, {Canadiens, Defense, Former}]
```

The schema is:

```
hockey_schema = StructType([

     StructField("player_name", StringType(), True),

     StructField("team_history", ArrayType(
         StructType([
             StructField("team",      StringType(), True),
             StructField("position",  StringType(), True),
             StructField("status",    StringType(), True),
         ])), True)

   ])
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
[{ "player_name" : "John", "team_history" : [ { "team" : "Rangers", "position" : "Center", "status" : "Active" }, { "team" : "Blackhawks", "position" : "Center", "status" : "Former"}, { "team" : "Kings", "position" : "Center", "status" : "Former"} ] },

{ "player_name" : "Bob", "team_history" : [ { "team" : "Devils", "position" : "Defense", "status" : "Active" }, { "team" : "Maple Leafs", "position" : "Defence", "status" : "Former"}, { "team" : "Canadiens", "position" : "Defense", "status" : "Former"} ] }]
```

I would like to "explode" the contents of the `team_history` column to create a new dataframe named `df_exploded` with columns for **only `team` and `status`** that looks like this:

```
team          status
Rangers       Active
Blackhawks    Former
Kings         Former
Devils        Active
Maple Leafs   Former
Canadiens     Former
```

How would I create the desired `df_exploded` dataframe using the `explode()` function in Pyspark?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explode array values using PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62643843/explode-array-values-using-pyspark)

Comment: where is the json stored? a file or in a dataframe? if in a dataframe, what is the column's data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that using `explode` and extracting the values you are interested in from the struct would do the trick:

```py
df\
  .select(F.explode("team_history").alias("s"))\
  .select("s.team", "s.status")\
  .show()
```

```
+-----------+------+
|team       |status|
+-----------+------+
|Rangers    |Active|
|Blackhawks |Former|
|Kings      |Former|
|Devils     |Active|
|Maple Leafs|Former|
|Canadiens  |Former|
+-----------+------+
```